# Modal Instance AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
   <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit"  ng-click="ok()">YES</button>
        <button type="submit"  ng-click="reset()">NO</button>
        *<button type="submit"  ng-click="cancel()">CANCEL</button>*
    </div>

 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
}
```

On YES button click, assigning selecteditem and NO closing modal popup. How possible if I add a new button CANCEL, and want to call another function?

My modal works like, Modal section in  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: You need to post more code of how your modal works

Comment: also, try to post some HTML as well